# Haskell Type Classes in Type Alias declaration

Tags: haskell, types, typeclass, generic-type-argument

I am trying to develop a module that performs different algorithms over a set of states by receiving the functions to manage them as paremeters. I was defining different type aliases to make it easier to implement; a simple example to understand this would be:

```
-- Function that expands a state
type Expand = State -> State
-- Function that evaluates a state
type Eval = State -> Float
-- Group of states
type Tree = [State]
```

And then I realized that I wanted `State` to be the alias of a type that is equatable: I really don't care if the user's states are `(Int, Int)`, `Float`, or `String` as long as it's possible for him to implement the `Expand` and `Eval` functions and for me to compare two different states.

How can I generalize the type `State` to achieve this? The intuitive thing that comes to my mind is something like `type State = (Eq a) => a` but that is obviously not possible without an `a` in scope. Is there an easy way for me to declare functions that treat `State` as a black box?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to include the generic state as a type parameter.

```
type Expand s = s -> s
type Eval s   = s -> Float
type Tree s   = [s]
```

It's impossible to completely hide it, because e.g. `Expand` for an `(Int, Int)` state is a completely different type than for a `String` state.

As for the `Eq` constraint. Typically, you would include that locally only in the specific function that requires the constraint.